# Multiple SubDomains

Tags: html, dns, subdomain

I know a few websites that has a url like

```
blog.contact.show.net
```

and etc etc.

Since im currently don't have a clue if this is even possible but it is, how in the heck do they do it? I mean like it would be cool to have a dev page like for a store

```
store.example.com
```

you could have

```
dev.store.example.com
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this works? Or is it mainly .htaccess? <- because im not good with using this :(. If it is with htaccess, can someone give an example on how to route things to a specific folder so i can have multiple subdomains.

Comment: How you configure your DNS depends on your DNS server. How you configure your web server depends on your webserver (in the case of Apache, you'd generally do it the main config level, not the per-directory `.htaccess` level).